# How to handle parent entity when saving both parent/child entities asynchronously?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
records_to_put = []
events_to_put = []

record = Record.get_or_insert(json_record['record_id'], ... )
records_to_put.append(rec)

event = Event.get_or_insert(json_event['event_id'], parent=record.key)
events_to_put.append(event)

ndb.put_multi_async(records_to_put)
ndb.put_multi_async(events_to_put)
```

`Event` will always be a child of a `Record`.  Due the asynchronous nature, what happens if `event` instance is saved first, while it's parent instance hasn't yet been saved.  Will it throw an exception or is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

If record entity already exists, there will be no problems with this code because this entity has a fully formed key.

If record entity is new, you have to put it first before you can use its key for a child entity. You will get an exception.

Comment: if you manually assign id/key_name then you can safely create the child before the parent.

Comment: @TimHoffman I have updated the question, and added the way I insert the IDs. In this case I should be safe correct?

Comment: Yes, if the parent key is not auto generated then you will always have the full key of the parent. That is the only thing preventing from writing children out first.